# API Manager Production and Sandbox port not longer displayed

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We have started using WSO2 API Manager 2.6.0, everything worked fine for some time, but now the port for the production and/or sandbox service endpoints is no longer displayed in the store console, when displaying the API. This happens on several independent machines. Is there a configuration parameter which needs to be set?
Not showing the port is not an option.
Before this the display was https://wso2server:8243/service-context 
and now, it has changed to : https://wso2server/service-context 
The service itself can be accessed only by setting the correct port (8243), using the url without the port will always be redirected to the /carbon login page.
The services are running as expected without any errors, when access with the correct port number.It is hard for the administrators to always remember the port numbers. The port number (8243) is set in axis2.xml (transportReceiver for https)

Does anyone has an idea?

Regards
Edmund

Comment: What do you have in the `Environments` section of `api-manager.xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the correct URL in the APIGateway section in api-manager.xml file which resides in APIM_HOME/repository/conf location. Under APIGateway,there is a section called GatewayEndpoint. You can specify the URLs as follows.

```
<GatewayEndpoint>http://wso2server:8280,https://wso2server:8243</GatewayEndpoint>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I used the variable ${https.nio.port} and now it is shown in the ui again. Thank you